# ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

We encountered an error when run spark-submit command on AWS EMR cluster.
Our spark job previously was running on HDP cluster without any additional configuration in a scala code. When we start the job all executors throw errors about connection to Zookeeper node that don't exist on core nodes of EMR.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, ip-10-239-130-44.ec2.internal, executor 3): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the location for replica 0
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextWithSyncCache(ClientScanner.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:597)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anon$2.hasNext(HBaseTableScan.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$JoinIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD$$anon$3.hasNext(HBaseTableScan.scala:314)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.get(ConnectionImplementation.java:2009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionImplementation.java:785)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:752)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.relocateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionImplementation.java:927)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:325)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/meta-region-server
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient$ZKTask$1.exec(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ReadOnlyZKClient.run(ReadOnlyZKClient.java:323)
    ... 1 more
```

The Spark command:

```
spark-submit \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark  \
--conf spark.executor.memory=4g \
--conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
--class app_name \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--jars ... -s hbase -i 13181_qatopilot -o /home/hadoop/s/d 2> last_ja-datascience.log
```

It seems that spark executor tried to connect on it's localhost to the port 2181 when actually Zookeeper node don't exist on executor:

```
20/02/02 09:00:19 WARN ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
20/02/02 09:00:19 WARN ReadOnlyZKClient: 0x19a6f47f to localhost:2181 failed for get of /hbase/hbaseid, code = CONNECTIONLOSS, retries = 28
20/02/02 09:00:20 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
20/02/02 09:00:20 WARN ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

Comment: `for server null`... Seems like a configuration issue

Comment: I suppose too that is a configuration issue but we need to configure? I already tried to add all *.xml configuration files to spark-submit by ```--files``` parameter and it didn;t work, tried also to export env variables with configuration paths.

Comment: Spark defaults to pickup the xml files in `SPARK_HOME/conf`. The fact that you've needed to pass `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv` means that you might be missing environment variables on your node manager machines. But Hbase requires Zookeeper to function, so it's running somewhere and I'm just pointing out that the logs probably shouldn't say `null`. Not clear what jars you're using though

Comment: I tried to export ```HADOOP_CONF_DIR``` and ```YARN_CONF_DIR``` env variables with the right paths but the job failed with the same error.

Comment: What anyway helped is ```--deploy mode cluster --master yarn```...

Comment: Exported those variables how/where? On which machines? For which users?

Comment: On the active master node with root user on the same session right before spark-submit command

Comment: That doesn't distibuted the variable to other NodeManagers. Only the driver. You'll have to update `spark-env.sh` or `/etc/profile` on every other node and restart YARN

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks!